# Compare two arrays with different size, elementwise?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, compare

Let say I have two array of different sizes :

```
In [79]: tr
Out[79]: array([1, 1, 0, 6, 0, 3])

In [80]: br
Out[80]: array([ 9, 26, 24, 18, 14, 12,  8])
```

I want to make sure all elements of br are bigger than all elements of tr i.e. br > tr

```
 ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6,) (7,)
```

Comment: Big than the corresponding elements (where they match)?  Or all?  Why not compare the `max` of one with the `min` of the other?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check if the minimum number in br is bigger than the maximum number in tr:

```
if min(br) > max(tr):
    # all the element in br are bigger 
else:
    # there is at least one value in tr bigger or equal than one value in br
```

Answer (score 1):

If it makes logical sense for your task, you could pad your shorter array with zeros:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 1, 0, 6, 0, 3])
b = np.array([ 9, 26, 24, 18, 14, 12,  8])

all(np.less_equal(np.pad(a,  (0, len(b) - len(a))), b))
```

```
True
```

What the smaller array looks like when padded:

```
array([1, 1, 0, 6, 0, 3, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see i have created 2 loops first for bigger size array and second for small size array

```
   for i in range(0,len(br)):
        for j in range(0,len(tr)):
            if(br[i]<tr[j]):
               #tr[j] is bigger than value in br[i]
```